# Encryption algorithms compatibility between Android Key Store and Apple Enclave

Tags: ios, iphone, cryptography, android-keystore, encryption-asymmetric

I have the scenario as explained below.

**Background
--------------**

I have 3 types of devices/users in my ecosystem. One type of device is Android, other is Apple iOS and third kind of device[user] is the cloud application.

**Scenario
-------------**

So my use case here is that either of the Android or iOS could be the producer of some 'data key'. And I am using Android Key Store on Android to do encryption/decryption while I am using the Secure Enclave on iOS for encryption/Decryption. The public key will be fetched from some common data store.

**Scenario 1:** iOS device fetches the public key of android device[user] from central data store and encrypts the data key using this public key using its Enclave algorithm and puts the encrypted data key on central data store.
Now Android will fetch this encrypted data key and will try to decrypt this using its private key on AndroidKeyStore.

Now here the challenge is how can I choose the same algorithm specification salt/padding/MGF1 etc. in order to successfully decrypt the data key? I want to have this kind of compatability?

I can handle the cloud application[user] by changing the java options as this application has been written in java.

**Scenario 2:** The second scenario is just similar to the scenario 1 above but in this scenario Android is encrypting and iOS is decrypting.

**My Approach On this So Far :**

I am thinking of using some independent security provider for example Bouncy Castle for all the encryption and decryption activity on either device or cloud application instead of using the on-device encryption/decryption.
But this is not so secure and will have the plain private key stored in memory of the application and hence increasing the risk.

I am sure this is not the first time this problem is being solved and there must be some approaches/algorithms available to make this happen.

Could some one please guide me on this.

Comment: This isn’t really anything to do with the Secure Enclave or the Android Key Store.  The enclave is used to store data securely on the device. If you want to share encrypted data then you need to code using the same encryption algorithm and parameters on all platforms. For example, Apple provides a Crypto framework in iOS that implements common hashing and encryption algorithms.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes that is one of the ways but that is less secure than the Secure Enclave and Android Key Store as using security framework provided by Device and coding around it brings private key in application memory.
So I was looking for the compatibility actually.

Comment: Ok. The Secure Enclave on iOS devices only supports 256 bit elliptic curve keys, so see if that is also supported by the Android Key Store https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave

Comment: @Ankit_ceo2 if you found any solution for the above requirement? I am also looking to implement the same kind of requirement. Please help me with this.